# Simple math with jQuery

Tags: jquery, math, sum, addition

i'm trying to do simple math with jquery, i've got to variables get from the form, and i wanna do something like 50 + onevariable - othervariable... my code look like this:

```
+ (50 + wymieniana - posiadana) +
```

i perform this inside of .html so... ale looks like:

```
$('#prize').html('<center><h6>Dopłata za wymianę wyniesie</h6>'+ (50 + wymieniana - posiadana) +'zł </center>');
```

the problem is when wymieniana = 70, and posiadana = 90
i don't get 50 + 20 = 70
but 5020
is there any solution of these?

Comment: What is there before and after first and last `+`? Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

> The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be
>   used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the
>   number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a
>   decimal number.
>
> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal) If the
>   string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>   (decimal)

```
(50 + parseInt(wymieniana, 10) - parseInt(posiadana, 10))
```